# How to correct the url in magento of website and admin panel?

Tags: magento

I am doing a project in Magento. I have uploaded my work onto a live server. I have updated the core_config_data table with the server urls in the secure and unsecure urls. But when  I typing the live server link, its going to the local server url and also when I am accessing the live servers admin panel its going to the local server url. Can anyone tell why it is like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing website from local to live you need to do following changes:

- change url's from core_config_data table
- change database details from local.xml
- and most important, Redirect problem was due to Magento cache.

  - Simply delete everything from the /var folder.

After performing the above changes, clear your browser's cache & cookies and check again.

Answer (score 0):

On your computer, check your hosts file and see if you have an entry for your domain. 
On windows: C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts
On mac or ubuntu: /etc/hosts

If you see an entry that shows:
127.0.0.1  www.mydomain.com or 
localhost  www.mydomain.com
then you should remove your entry.

You should also flush the dns cache.

Whenever I work locally, I use the subdomain 'local' like local.mydomain.com and this way I dont have to worry about these issues.

Also, you should fully delete the var folder, it is safe to do so.